# Trying to return class type but error with template parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I have a total of 5 functions for overloading &, +, -, *, and / in a class that only has a dynamically created array with arrSize as a private member. I am also using a template to universalize the class and its overloaded functions. In each of the 5 functions I'm having trouble with, I'm getting the error invalid use of template-name 'SmartArray' without argument list. Here are my functions:

```
/* function description: overrides the & operator. Lets us concatenate two arrays together.
   parameters:           const SmartArray& numArray is the right-hand array being concatenated to the left-hand array.
   return value:         void
*/
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray<ArrType>& SmartArray::operator&(const SmartArray& numArray) const{
    SmartArray concatenate(arrSize+numArray.length());   // creating object with array large enough to hold both arrays.
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)        // putting left-hand array into concatenated array
        concatenate.elements[i] = elements[i];
    for(int i=arrSize; i<arrSize+numArray.length(); i++)    // puts in right-hand array elements second
        concatenate.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i-arrSize];

    return concatenate;
}

/* function description: overrides + operator. Lets us add the contents of two arrays together.
   parameters:           const SmartArray& numArray is the right-hand array being added to the left-hand array.
   return value:         SmartArray
*/
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray SmartArray::operator+(const SmartArray& numArray) const{
    SmartArray added;    // initializes array to hold added arrays
    if(arrSize > numArray.length()){    // checks which array is larger, then creates new array with the larger size
        SmartArray added(arrSize);
        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            added.elements[i] += numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=numArray.length(); i<arrSize; i++)
            added.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }else if(arrSize <= numArray.length()){
        SmartArray added(numArray.length());
        for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            added.elements[i] += numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=arrSize; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            added.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }
    return added;
}

/* function description: overrides + operator. Lets us subtract the contents of two arrays together.
   parameters:           const SmartArray& numArray is the right-hand array being subtracted to the left-hand array.
   return value:         SmartArray
*/
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray SmartArray::operator-(const SmartArray& numArray) const{
    SmartArray subtracted;    // initializes array to hold subtracted arrays
    if(arrSize > numArray.length()){    // checks which array is larger, then creates new array with the larger size
        SmartArray subtracted(arrSize);
        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            subtracted.elements[i] -= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=numArray.length(); i<arrSize; i++)
            subtracted.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }else if(arrSize <= numArray.length()){
        SmartArray subtracted(numArray.length());
        for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            subtracted.elements[i] -= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=arrSize; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            subtracted.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }
    return subtracted;
}

/* function description: overrides + operator. Lets us multiply the contents of two arrays together.
   parameters:           const SmartArray& numArray is the right-hand array being multiplied to the left-hand array.
   return value:         SmartArray
*/
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray SmartArray::operator*(const SmartArray& numArray) const{
    SmartArray multiplied;    // initializes array to hold multiplied arrays
    if(arrSize > numArray.length()){    // checks which array is larger, then creates new array with the larger size
        SmartArray multiplied(arrSize);
        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            multiplied.elements[i] *= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=numArray.length(); i<arrSize; i++)
            multiplied.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }else if(arrSize <= numArray.length()){
        SmartArray multiplied(numArray.length());
        for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            multiplied.elements[i] *= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=arrSize; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            multiplied.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }
    return multiplied;
}

/* function description: overrides + operator. Lets us divide the contents of two arrays together.
   parameters:           const SmartArray& numArray is the right-hand array being divided to the left-hand array.
   return value:         SmartArray
*/
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray SmartArray::operator/(const SmartArray& numArray) const{
    SmartArray divided;    // initializes array to hold divided arrays
    if(arrSize > numArray.length()){    // checks which array is larger, then creates new array with the larger size
       SmartArray divided(arrSize);
        for(int i=0; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            divided.elements[i] /= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=numArray.length(); i<arrSize; i++)
            divided.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }else if(arrSize <= numArray.length()){
        SmartArray divided(numArray.length());
        for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            divided.elements[i] /= numArray.elements[i];
        for(int i=arrSize; i<numArray.length(); i++)
            divided.elements[i] = numArray.elements[i];
    }
    return divided;
}
```

With the very first function, I tried using

```
SmartArray<ArrType>& SmartArray::.....
```

but I got the error "'template class SmartArray' used without template parameters."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere you use the `SmartArray` type, you need to include the templated type to use.  For example,

```
template <class ArrType>
SmartArray<ArrType> SmartArray<ArrType>::operator&(const SmartArray<ArrType>& numArray) const{
    SmartArray<ArrType> concatenate(arrSize+numArray.length());
```

Note the addition of `<ArrType>` to the declaration of `numArray` in the parameter list and the `concatenate` local variable.  I've also removed the `&` from the function return type, since you don't want to return a reference to a local variable.

You'll have to make similar changes to your other functions.

Comment: That worked! Just to let you know, though, I also needed to add "<ArrType>" before every double colon (::).